# Fail to import data to Neo4j by using spreadsheet way

Tags: neo4j, spreadsheet

I want to import data to Neo4j and follow the instruction in below link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ah0qwaznhrupdF9kaDZDNWViM05UeVBfdTJmcHpQckE&usp=sharing)#gid=3

I can import data successfully, but when I use Cypher to query such as `match (n) return n;`, the result is null...

[image]
[image]

Below are the contents of data and properties setting:

`1.Instruction`

```
cat import.txt | bin/neo4j-shell -config conf/neo4j.properties -path data/graph.db
```

`2.import.txt`

```
BEGIN
create (n:Female {id:1, name:'Amada Emory'});
create (n:Female {id:2, name:'Rana Seely'});
create (n:Female {id:3, name:'Detra Thatcher'});
create (n:Female {id:4, name:'Melda Reza'});
create (n:Female {id:5, name:'Shana Willems'});
create (n:Female {id:6, name:'Sharonda Peele'});
create (n:Female {id:7, name:'Dagny Agee'});
create (n:Female {id:8, name:'Tisa Woodman'});
create (n:Female {id:9, name:'Shelba Mutchler'});
create (n:Male {id:10, name:'Anderson Spagnola'});
create (n:Female {id:11, name:'Pamala Forward'});
create (n:Female {id:12, name:'Melva Fairchild'});
create (n:Male {id:13, name:'Antione Selman'});
create (n:Female {id:14, name:'Carmelia Cali'});
create (n:Female {id:15, name:'Fairy Daughtery'});
create (n:Female {id:16, name:'Stefany Mcamis'});
create (n:Male {id:17, name:'Kermit Meaney'});
create (n:Female {id:18, name:'Williemae Dossantos'});
create (n:Female {id:19, name:'Marth Sparling'});
create (n:Male {id:20, name:'Jarvis Noland'});
match (from {id:1}), (to {id:11}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:1}), (to {id:12}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:1}), (to {id:13}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:2}), (to {id:14}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:2}), (to {id:15}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:2}), (to {id:16}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:3}), (to {id:17}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:3}), (to {id:18}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:3}), (to {id:19}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:10}), (to {id:20}) create from-[:FATHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:14}), (to {id:1}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:11}), (to {id:2}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:11}), (to {id:3}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:12}), (to {id:4}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:12}), (to {id:5}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:12}), (to {id:6}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:17}), (to {id:7}) create from-[:FATHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:13}), (to {id:8}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:13}), (to {id:9}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
match (from {id:20}), (to {id:1}) create from-[:FATHER_OF]->to;
COMMIT
```

`3.neo4j-server.properties`

```
...
# location of the database directory 
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db
...
```

`neo4j.properties`

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
#neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
#neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=50M
#neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
#neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
#neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version
#allow_store_upgrade=true

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher_parser_version=2.0

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true"
keep_logical_logs=true

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
#node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#node_keys_indexable=id,name,type

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
#relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#relationship_keys_indexable=name,age

# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
#remote_shell_enabled=true
# Specify custom shell port (default is 1337).
#remote_shell_port=1234
```

But if I Add `COMMIT` and `BEGIN` between create and match block, the node will be added successfully, however the relationship is failed...
The format of `import.txt` is:

```
BEGIN
...
    create (n:Male {id:20, name:'Jarvis Noland'});
COMMIT
BEGIN
    match (from {id:1}), (to {id:11}) create from-[:MOTHER_OF]->to;
...
COMMIT
```

Could someone tell me why? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't trust the node-count on that screen, it only lists the records that were created in the files, even if they were never used or never committed.

1. Make sure your server is not running when you use `-path` or don't use that parameter and connect to the running server.
2. What is the output from your load script?
3. Use labels and an index on :Label(id) to match your nodes better.